# PHP slim application is not run?

Tags: php, mysql, slim, slim-3

I am new with Slim framework and currently I am creating a service for login and registration with it.

I created a database file in lib for `database.php` and put following code in that file for select data for user.

```
<?php 
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require 'lib/mysql.php';

class DatabseLayer{
    public function __constructor(){

    }


     public function isUserExist($email, $password){
        $dbObject = new DbConnect();
        $sql = "Select * from users where email = $email and password = $password limit 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbObject->getDb(), $sql);
        if(count($result) > 0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;       
    }
}
?>
```

then i have put following code in index.php file

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
//require 'lib/mysql.php';


require 'lib/database.php';


$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->get('/:email/:password', function($email, $password){

    $password = md5($password);

    $databaseObject = new DatabaseLayer();
    $isRegistered = $databaseObject->isUserExist($email, $password);

    $app = SlimSlim::getInstance();

    if($isRegistered){
        $app->response->setStatus('200');   
        $app->response->headers->set('Content_Type', 'application/json');   
        echo json_encode(Array('isLogin' => '1'));

    }else{
        echo json_encode(Array('isLogin' => '0'));
    }

});


$app->run();

?>
```

and when I try to login with this URL

`http://localhost/slim/test@test.com/11111`

or

`http://localhost/slim/index.php/test@test.com/11111`

it gives me a page not found error. I don't have any more ideas so can anyone help.

Comment: please read about mysql injections and use prepared statements or at least escape values before using them in a query. also having login credentials in the get url is a bad idea. they might be visible in REFERER header to third party websites and will show up in logs, browser history and so on

Comment: What version of slim are you using? You appear to be mixing Slim 2 and Slim 3 code which will not work together.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring routes in Slim 2 manner, while using Slim 3. Your application has only one route which is literally `website.com/:email/:password`. Therefore you get `404` error.

Slim 3 uses fast route and instead of specifying placeholders in this manner:

```
'/:email/:password'
```

you should declare them this way:

```
'/{email}/{password}'
```

You can read more about ways of declaring routes in [corresponding section of Slim documentation](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#how-to-create-routes) or [nikic/fastRoute github repository](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute#usage).